# Problems with powershell script to handle not responding exe

Tags: powershell, process

I have copied this script, maybe from here. It is standard Powershell script to constantly monitor application (exe), which uses to hang in every 2 days. Application is called HCSCOM and it's used for importing reservations in our hotel system. So, I must constantly check it if it's stuck, by logging remotely into the computer 3 times per day. Ok, so - this script is showing me messages that process HCSCOM is running.

```
$ProcessName = "HCSCOM"

While($True) {
    $Process = Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($Process -eq $Null) {
        Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is not running. Restarting now..."
        # If the process is a service
        # Start-Service -Name $ProcessName

        # If the process is an executable, uncomment the following line and replace with the correct path
        Start-Process -FilePath "D:\HOTELSYS\HCSCOM\HCSCOM.exe"
    }
    else {
        # Check if the process is not responding
        $WmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId = $($Process.Id)"
        if ($WmiObject.Status -eq "Not Responding") {
            Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is not responding. Restarting now..."

            # Stop the process
            Stop-Process -Name $ProcessName -Force

            # Start the process again
            # If the process is a service
            # Start-Service -Name $ProcessName

            # If the process is an executable, uncomment the following line and replace with the correct path
            Start-Process -FilePath "D:\HOTELSYS\HCSCOM\HCSCOM.exe"
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is running."
        }
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 180  # checks every 180 seconds
}
```

But today I've found out that process is in state Not Responding, and it doesnt kill the process, it gives me this error when I run again the script. There is something wrong with select query, but I cant figure out what it is.

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId=6512 13196
"
At C:\Users\PC\Desktop\scripthcscom.ps1:16 char:22
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId=6512 13196
"
At C:\Users\PC\Desktop\scripthcscom.ps1:16 char:22
+ ... WmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Process Where P ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Command 
   s.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I haven't tried anything. I think that there is problem with this sql statement  $WmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId = $($Process.Id)" , but can't figure out.

Comment: Are you sure "Not Responding" is what you're looking for? It's not in the list of possible values for the `Status` property in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process - you probably want to test `if($WmiObject.Status -notin "OK","Starting","Stopping"){ ... }` instead

Comment: The cause of the error is that you are getting two processes from `Get-Process`, yet your code assumes it will be only one. This can be seen in the error message `ProcessId = 6512 13196`, where two PIDs are listed. Use `Select-Object -First 1` to make sure you handle only one process at a time: `$Process = Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1` or use a `ForEach` loop over `$Process`.

Comment: As an aside: Not only does `Not Responding` not appear to be among the documented `.ExecutionState` values (`.Status` is documented as _never having a value_), and on my W11 22H2 machine I never see any values for any running processes, even when I run with elevation.

Comment: I remember that I've started the script once again, while the process was in not responding state. Maybe that's why it showed 2 PIDs at the same time - ProcessId = 6512 13196.  But the problem is where I can check for $WmiObject.Status values? PC is running Win10. Maybe I should use $WmiObject.State ? I cant see properties in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Maybe I should embed somewhere this line?
Get-Process | ?{$_.Responding -like "False"};

Comment: I think you're right about the .status property. When I run this command

Get-WmiObject -Query "select * from win32_service   |  Format-List -Property PSComputerName, Name, ExitCode, Name, ProcessID, StartMode, State, Status
i see the state property as running or stopped. 

But for a process (changing to win32_process) i see the following properties - PSComputerName, Name, Name, ProcessID and Status which is empty.

Comment: This is my complete script

    else {
        # Check if the process is not responding
        # $WmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId = $($Process.Id)"
        # if ($WmiObject.State -eq "Not Responding")
        if ((Get-Process -id $($Process.Id)).Responding -like "False")
        {
            Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is not responding. Restarting now..."

            # Stop the process
            Stop-Process -Name $ProcessName -Force

It is working, only I need to make it restart if the process hangs after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is my complete script

```
$ProcessName = "HCSCOM"
```

While($True) {
$Process = Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1

```
if ($Process -eq $Null) {
    Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is not running. Restarting now..."
    # If the process is a service
    # Start-Service -Name $ProcessName

    # If the process is an executable, uncomment the following line and replace with the correct path
    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\HOTELSYS\HCSCOM\HCSCOM.exe"
}
else {
    # Check if the process is not responding
    # $WmiObject = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessId = $($Process.Id)"
    # if ($WmiObject.State -eq "Not Responding")
    if ((Get-Process -id $($Process.Id)).Responding -like "False")
    {
        Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is not responding. Restarting now..."

        # Stop the process
        Stop-Process -Name $ProcessName -Force

        # Start the process again
        # If the process is a service
        # Start-Service -Name $ProcessName

        # If the process is an executable, uncomment the following line and replace with the correct path
        Start-Process -FilePath "D:\HOTELSYS\HCSCOM\HCSCOM.exe"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "The process $ProcessName is running."
    }
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 600  # checks every 180 seconds
```

}

The only thing I need now is to make it wait before it restarts when the process is not responding. And definitely the status property has no values, only the responding flag.